# How to replace fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, fragment

I have a problem when i perform a search view. My searchview is using onQuetyTextChanged, to show the search result every time the text is changed. I want the data to return to its original state when the text input is deleted. I use this code `transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, moviesFragment);` to restore the fragment, but the search result fragment is still behind the original fragment like image below. How to delete the fragment of the search results?

[Image after performing search.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWjHC.png)
This is my searchView code

```
 final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) (menu.findItem(R.id.search)).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.length() > 0) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("query", newText);
                    SearchMovieFragment fragment = new SearchMovieFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, moviesFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/color_primary_gradient"
    app:tabTextColor="#D4AF37"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The default color is transparent.

Set the background color in your Fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option
1. set your layout background color to white or any

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

2.

```
 Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Comment: In starting of the else part of onQueryTextChange method.

Comment: It caused a NullPointerException

Comment: how can i change the background color at backstack to white ?

Comment: Give background color in XML file of your movies Fragment

Comment: If i change the color to white, then when i perform the search all the result will be white, looks like empty